# Pick value stored against a hash key which ends with a specific character

Tags: swift, hash, swift2

I have a hash of type `[String: [String: AnyObject]]()` something like below,

```
{ 
  "asndfkjsndkjnf_1": {"A": "2"}, 
  "jckxjbcvkjbsdsdfkz_2": {"G": 3},
  "sahgkshbgskdssjf_3": {"T": '1'},
  "asdhlsfldsnfsldk_4": {"C": 4}
}
```

I want to pick the value of hash entry whose key ends with `"_1"`, since hashes don't have indexes I am finding it a bit difficult to retrieve item I want without knowing the complete key.

Comment: I am using Ruby for backend and now coding Swift for ios app, its getting mixed up :) Help!

Comment: Help is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Comment: Went through the docs already, thing is I don't know the complete key to retrieve the value, I only know that the hash's key ends with a certain pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way of fetching a value from a dictionary by using optional binding:

```
let dict: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "asndfkjsndkjnf_1": ["A": "2"],
    "jckxjbcvkjbsdsdfkz_2": ["G": 3],
    "sahgkshbgskdssjf_3": ["T": "1"],
    "asdhlsfldsnfsldk_4": ["C": 4]
]

if let innerDict = dict["asndfkjsndkjnf_1"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print(innerDict)
    if let valueA = innerDict["A"] as? String {
        print(valueA)
    }
}
```

But in a comment you say

> I don't know the complete key to retrieve the value, I only know that the hash's key ends with a certain pattern

You can use `.hasSuffix()` to find which key ends with a certain string, then use this key to fetch the inner value.

Let's say you want to find the value for the key ending with "_3":

```
for key in dict.keys where key.hasSuffix("_3") {
    if let innerDict = dict[key] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(innerDict)
        if let innerValue = innerDict["T"] as? String {
            print(innerValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know there was a `hasSuffix` function, I was thinking of using regex for matching, which was making things complicated in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` has a `keys` property that lets you (lazily) evaluate all the keys of the dictionary, so you can just use:

```
let foo = [
    "asndfkjsndkjnf_1": ["A": "2"],
    "jckxjbcvkjbsdsdfkz_2": ["G": 3],
    "sahgkshbgskdssjf_3": ["T": "1"],
    "asdhlsfldsnfsldk_4": ["C": 4]
]

if let match = foo.keys.filter({ (key) -> Bool in key.hasSuffix("_1") }).first {
    // foo[match] will be the first matched dictionary
    print("\(foo[match])")
}
```

another possibility is to just filter the whole dictionary for matching keys:

```
foo.filter({ $0.0.hasSuffix("_1") }).first?.1
```